# What is the difference between these two ceiling wire configurations?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling, lamp

I see two types of ceiling wire configurations in a flat (in Germany). They seem to be both 3-wire, but each type of wire is doubled in the first type, compared to the second type.

The first type is only seen immediately at the entrance to the flat (in the corridor), while the second type is seen everywhere else in the flat (6 other places).

Is the first type of wire configuration intended for something other than ceiling lamps? Or can they be treated as the same. (And is the tenant still supposed to install a ceiling lamp there.) I don't understand the purpose for every type of wire to be doubled there. (Little experience in home improvement/electrical work).

I've also attached a photo of the whole corridor. Seems to me it would be a bit weird to install two ceiling lamps in such close proximity to each other, but maybe that's the intention anyways?

Thanks!

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Corridor]

Comment: Usually with double wire sets it is one light, but the power also goes to another light somewhere else.  Single sets are at the end of a line or just go to that light and no where else.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for the prompt reply. Does it mean that from the tenant's perspective there's no difference between the double wire set and the single wire set (i.e. at both places the tenant can only install one light in the same fashion)

Comment: A single light fixture, which might contain more than one light.

Comment: @crip659 Right. Thank for the info.